# How to implement "if error occurs do not implement this code"?

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to write a code in python that basically does something like this:

```
if error occurs while implementing int(a) print('valid character')
elif no error occurs while implementing int(a)  print('invalid character')
```

`a` is an input.

I want to make a simple hangman game and if the input is not a letter I want a certain message to be displayed. I tried using `if a==int()`, but inputs are always a string.

Comment: Use `try/catch`

Comment: Testing if `int(a)` raises an exception is not a good test that `a` is a letter. Consider `int("=")`. Maybe testing `isalpha()` is a better approach.

Comment: @Barmar any particular reason you recommend `try/catch` for " if the input is not a letter"? I would expect python to have functions to check that without an exception … https://www.bing.com/search?q=python+if+the+input+is+not+a+letter suggest `isalpha`...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I was suggesting it for "input is not a number", not "input is not a letter".

Comment: @Barmar I see. Good thing OP actually included what they are trying to achieve in addition to what code they have.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I was going by "if error occurs while implementing int(a)". I didn't notice that he was trying to use this for something different.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would use a [Try, Except clause](http://'https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions') to handle errors, but because you're not actually getting an error -- you just want to know if the input is an alphabetical character or not, you would use the [string.isalpha](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) function.

```
guess = input()
if not guess.isalpha():
    print('You must supply an alphabetical character')
else:
    #the rest of your code would go here
```

---

---

Now to have some fun. This is how you would implement exactly what you where asking, however, please note that this does not catch punctuation characters, emoji characters, and any other random characters that are none-numeric and non-alphabetical.

```
guess = input()
isOk = False

try:
   int(guess)
except ValueError:
    isOk = True

if not isOk:
    print("you cannot enter a number")
```

I don't know if it's a good idea to mention this or not, because it's a pretty quirky feature of Python to add the else here, but you can technically condense the above code to

```
guess = input()
try:
   int(guess)
except ValueError:
    # All good
    pass
else:
    # we where able to cast to an integer = bad
    print("you cannot enter a number")
```

but I probably wouldn't ever do that in production code. Also, an important note. As you learn about try except clauses. Even though it's possible to just do `except:` Make sure you always state whatever you are catching. In this case a ValueError `except ValueError:` . If you don't do this, you suppress all errors, and you risk getting into a situation down the road were an important error gets suppressed, and you have no idea why your program is behaving incorrectly.

Comment: I believe you meant to initialize `isOk = False` and in the except `isOk = True`?

Comment: Whoops. I shouldn't have been multitasking while I was testing out the code. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

explore try-except designs

```
try:
   # do something here
except (ErrorName):
   # error catching
   print("invalid character")
```

Please try and include reproducible code, or a code block of pseudo-code so others can follow along easier!